# Plotting after solving equations

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I obtained a list of Y list after using `Table[NSolve[expression,X],{var,varmin,varmax,step}]`. Then I created a list of X with `Range`. I concatenated both of these lists and took the transpose to get x,y points. I need to plot the two lists. I think I am getting issue because of the `X->` obtained in the list. Can anyone tell how to get rid of `X->` in the list. It seems something trivial but I don't seem to know it.

Some points of the list {{0.1,X->0.333333}, {0.2,X->0.5}, {0.3,X->0.6}, {0.4,X->0.666667}} .

Code

```
expression = k1 *kinase *(Xtot - X) - k11 *phase* X == 0;
phase = 0.2; k1 = 1; k11 = 1; Xtot = 1;
Yvalues = Table[NSolve[expression, X], {kinase , 0.1, 2, 0.1}] // Flatten;
Xvalues = Range[0.1, 2, 0.1];
Finallist = Transpose[{Xvalues,Yvalues}]
ListPlot[Finallist]
```

If anyone knows a better way to plot it would be much better.

Comment: Change the definition of `Yvalues` to `Yvalues = Table[X /. NSolve[expression, X], {kinase, 0.1, 2, 0.1}] // Flatten;`

Comment: See also `Values`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it for you

```
    expression = k1*kinase*(Xtot - X) - k11*phase*X == 0;
    phase = 0.2; k1 = 1; k11 = 1; Xtot = 1;
    Yvalues = 
      Table[X /. NSolve[expression, X], {kinase, 0.1, 2, 0.1}] // Flatten;
    Xvalues = Range[0.1, 2, 0.1];
    Finallist = Transpose[{Xvalues, Yvalues}];
    ListPlot[Finallist]
    ListLinePlot[Finallist]
```

[image: Output plot]

[image: With line]

You need to look up `ReplaceAll` to get rid of the `X->` The output is in this form to prevent X being set to a numerical value.
Also note that it is best to use lower case variables since these won't clash with Mathematica variables.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to get a line connecting all these points?

Comment: See edit.......

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
expression = k1*kinase*(Xtot - X) - k11*phase*X == 0;
phase = 0.2; k1 = 1; k11 = 1; Xtot = 1;
Yvalues = 
  Table[Solve[expression, X], {kinase, 0.1, 2, 0.1}] // Flatten;
Xvalues = Range[0.1, 2, 0.1];
finallist = Transpose[{Xvalues, Yvalues}] /. {a_, X -> b_} -> {a, b}

(*
{{0.1, 0.333333}, {0.2, 0.5}, {0.3, 0.6}, {0.4, 0.666667}, {0.5, 
  0.714286}, {0.6, 0.75}, {0.7, 0.777778}, {0.8, 0.8}, {0.9, 
  0.818182}, {1., 0.833333}, {1.1, 0.846154}, {1.2, 0.857143}, {1.3, 
  0.866667}, {1.4, 0.875}, {1.5, 0.882353}, {1.6, 0.888889}, {1.7, 
  0.894737}, {1.8, 0.9}, {1.9, 0.904762}, {2., 0.909091}}
*)
```

Then

```
ListPlot[finallist]
```

yielding this:

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: By the way, you could make your final list in a more concise way: `finallist = 
 Table[{kinase, Solve[expression, X][[1, 1, 2]]}, {kinase, 0.1, 2, 0.1}]`.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem can be solved exactly.

```
expression = k1*kinase*(Xtot - X) - k11*phase*X == 0;
phase = 1/5; k1 = 1; k11 = 1; Xtot = 1;
```

As with the other solutions, using [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html)

```
x[kinase_] = X /. Solve[expression, X][[1]]

(* (5 kinase)/(1 + 5 kinase) *)

Plot[x[kinase], {kinase, 0, 2},
 AxesLabel -> {"kinase", "X"},
 PlotRange->All] (* EDIT: Added PlotRange -> All *)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We can directly use `ContourPlot` to plot the solution of the equation `k1*kinase*(Xtot - X) - k11*phase*X`.

```
phase = 0.2; k1 = 1; k11 = 1; Xtot = 1;
ContourPlot[
 k1*kinase*(Xtot - X) - k11*phase*X == 0, {kinase, 0.1, 2}, {X, 0.1, 
  2}]
```

[image]